# Trying to switch from Win7 to Ubuntu but boot disc won't work

Tags: boot

Okay, I have Win7 Ultimate on a machines, and I want to put Ubuntu 12.4 on it instead. I made a boot disc, flipped my boot order to CD first in my BIOS. It gets a little ways in to POST, and says "Booting from CD..."

Then it just starts windows anyway without doing any Ubuntu boot stuff at all. But it doesn't boot right to Windows, it boots to a 'Windows has failed to properly load, enter start repair or start windows normally screen.

Anyone have any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the CD you have isn't a bootable disc.
Maybe, you might've simply copied over files from the ISO or the ISO file might've been corrupted or incomplete.

Make sure you download the ISO file from the official page.

Here are instructions on how to make a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

And how to make a bootable DVD for Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

I have personally tried the method with the USB stick and it works fine. I also recommend it over the DVD method because you may have to throw away the DVD the process of burning doesn't complete properly.